# Conditional expectation and optimization

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convex-optimization

Let $x$ and $z$ be two real random variables with unknown joint distribution but satisfying the following relations:
\begin{equation}
 E\{x|z\}=\mu_0 \triangleq \mu(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0,z),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
var\{x|z\}=s_0 \triangleq s(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0,z),
\end{equation}
for some $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^p$. Let us now define the following function
\begin{equation}
l(\boldsymbol{\theta};x,z) \triangleq 2^{-1}\ln 2 \pi s(\boldsymbol{\theta},z) + \frac{(x-\mu(\boldsymbol{\theta},z))^2}{2s(\boldsymbol{\theta},z)}.
\end{equation}

I should show that $\bar{l}(\boldsymbol{\theta})\triangleq E_{x,z}\{l(\boldsymbol{\theta};x,z)\}$ is uniquely minimized by $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very roundabout way of saying that

$$
\mathsf E\left[\ln b+\frac{(x-a)^2}b\right]
$$

is minimized by $a=\mathsf E[x]$ and $b=\mathsf{Var}(x)$, which follows immediately by setting the derivative with respect to $a$ and $b$ to zero.

Comment: Yes, using your suggestion I can show that $\tilde{l}(\boldsymbol{\theta},z)\triangleq E_{x|z}\{l(\boldsymbol{\theta};x,z)|z\}$ is minimized by $\mu(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0,z)$ and $s(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0,z)$ for every realization of $z$. But from this, how can I show that $\bar{l}(\boldsymbol{\theta})\triangleq E_{x,z}\{l(\boldsymbol{\theta};x,z)\}$ is uniquely minimized by $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$?

Comment: @Vuk: I don't understand the "uniquely" part. You haven't told us anything about the functions $\mu$ and $s$; for all we know, they might take the values they take at $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ also at other values of $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, so I see no basis for concluding that the minimum is unique. As regards the expectation over $z$, if the expression is minimized by $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ for all realizations of $z$, then this is also true for the expectation over $z$, no?

Comment: @ joriki Ok, forget the "uniquely" part. I cannot convince myself (and I wasn't able to prove) about this: "As regards the expectation over $z$, if the expression is minimized by $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ for all realizations of $z$, then this is also true for the expectation over $z$, no?" Maybe it is a very easy step, but I'm not able to prove it... :)

Comment: @Vuk: I may be missing something (I'm better at actually doing stuff with random variables than at formally proving things about them :-), but isn't this just the [monotonicity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Monotonicity)?

Comment: Ok, thanks! True, I can use the proof of the monotonicity of the expectation.